# Storing a String and a List<Tuple> into a HashMap

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I have a `String id` and a `List<Tuple>` of data.
I need to store this data into a `HashMap` such that Id is the key and list is the value. How can I achieve this in Java?

Comment: Hard to give you an accurate snippet that fits your needs without seeing your actual code and how you plan to aggregate those values.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with something like below format.

```java
Map<String, List<Tuple>> map = new HashMap<>(); //Define new map
List<Tuple> list = new ArrayList<>();

//build your tuples here;
map.put("id", list); // Put them into map witk key- your id
```

Comment: Need a help. I have stored the key-value pair in hash map where key is an ID and value is the List<Tuple>.I need to fetch the data present in the list and insert in a MYSQL table. Could i get help on that?